# Will New Chunks Contain New Blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to start a server with some friends ASAP, but there's one problem: I also want the aquatic update stuff.

"All of these updates have been, or are set to be released in Q2 2018." So, I can either wait for a month at max (if this estimate is right), or I can start now.

So here's my question: if I start it now, and don't explore the ocean too much, will I get all the new blocks generated in new chunks?

Comment: Im gonna guess no. When you create a server, youre running a specific version of minecraft. If they update the game, they will release a new version, meaning in order for your server to get the updates, you would have to update the version the server runs.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does the snapshot server not work for you?

Comment: I'm personally inclined to guess yes, because of Grian's SMP and the current answer. Between versions of updating, new chunks were added in Grian's world. However, I'm not sure if this was just between beta versions, or it still works now. Also, where can I get the download for the snapshot server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you update your server after the release but keep the same world, new chunks will generate the new content.